# Extract map(varchar, array(varchar)) - Hive SQL

Tags: sql, arrays, json, hive, hiveql

I have a field which I think contains json strings

Example: `{"color": ["blue"], "fruit": ["apple", "cherry", "banana"]}`

how do I filter for records where color = blue?

Answer (score 2):

In the comment to the @GordonLinoff answer you mentioned `presto` error. If you are using Presto, use these recipes, also see solution for Hive below:

If the data type is JSON string, you can cast it to `map(varchar, array(varchar))`, then use `where contains(map['color'],'blue')` to filter it:

```
select * 
from
(--cast JSON string as MAP(VARCHAR,ARRAY(VARCHAR)) 
select '{"color": ["blue"], "fruit": ["apple", "cherry", "banana"]}' as original_string,
       CAST(JSON '{"color": ["blue"], "fruit": ["apple", "cherry", "banana"]}' AS MAP(VARCHAR,ARRAY(VARCHAR)) ) as mymap
)s
where contains(mymap['color'],'blue')
```

Result:

```
    original_string                                            mymap    
{"color": ["blue"], "fruit": ["apple", "cherry", "banana"]}    {'color': ['blue'], 'fruit': ['apple', 'cherry', 'banana']}
```

One more approach is to use `json_parse` + `json_extract` + `json_array_contains`:

```
select *
from
(--Parse JSON 
select '{"color": ["blue"], "fruit": ["apple", "cherry", "banana"]}' as original_string,
      json_parse( '{"color": ["blue"], "fruit": ["apple", "cherry", "banana"]}' ) as myjson
)s
WHERE json_array_contains(json_extract(myjson, '$.color'),'blue')
```

Result:

```
    original_string                                            myjson
{"color": ["blue"], "fruit": ["apple", "cherry", "banana"]}    {'color': ['blue'], 'fruit': ['apple', 'cherry', 'banana']}
```

**If the data type is already  `map(varchar, array(varchar))`** then just use `contains(field['color'],'blue')`

**If you are using Hive SQL**, then use get_json_object to extract color array (get_json_object always returns string), remove double-quotes and square brackets, split to get array and check using array_contains:

```
WHERE array_contains(split(regexp_replace(get_json_object(field,'$.color'),'"|^\\[|\\]$',''),','),'blue')
```

**And if you are using Hive and field is of `map<string,array<string>>` type**, use this:

```
array_contains(field['color'],'blue')
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use `like`:

```
where field like '%"color":["blue"]%'
```

This looks for exactly that pattern in the string.

Comment: it's not a regular string, so i'd get error like this:
presto error: line 4:5: Left side of LIKE expression must evaluate to a varchar (actual: map(varchar, array(varchar)))

Comment: @CuriousCat Is it hive or Presto? If Presto, please add Presto tag

Comment: @CuriousCat . . . Hive does not return "presto" errors.  Something is amiss in the question.