# pyspark hive sql convert array(map(varchar, varchar)) to string by rows

Tags: sql, pyspark, hive, presto

I would like to transform a column of

```
   array(map(varchar, varchar))
```

to string as rows of a table on presto db by pyspark hive sql programmatically from jupyter notebook python3.

example

```
user_id     sport_ids
 'aca'       [ {'sport_id': '5818'}, {'sport_id': '6712'}, {'sport_id': '1065'} ]
```

expected results

```
  user_id.    sport_ids
  'aca'.          '5815'
  'aca'.          '5712'
  'aca'.          '1065'
```

I have tried

```
     sql_q= """
            select distinct, user_id, transform(sport_ids, x -> element_at(x, 'sport_id')
            from tab """
            
     spark.sql(sql_q)
```

but got error:

```
   '->' cannot be resolved
```

I have also tried

```
  sql_q= """
            select distinct, user_id, sport_ids
            from tab"""
            
     spark.sql(sql_q)
```

but got error:

```
    org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot have map type columns in DataFrame which calls set operations(intersect, except, etc.), but the type of column request_features[0] is map<string,string>;;
```

Did I miss something ?

I have tried this, but helpful
[hive convert array<map<string, string>> to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72197870/hive-convert-arraymapstring-string-to-string)
[Extract map(varchar, array(varchar)) - Hive SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68960284/extract-mapvarchar-arrayvarchar-hive-sql)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Lets try use higher order functions to find map values and explode into individual rows

```
df.withColumn('sport_ids', explode(expr("transform(sport_ids, x->map_values(x)[0])"))).show()


+-------+---------+
|user_id|sport_ids|
+-------+---------+
|    aca|     5818|
|    aca|     6712|
|    aca|     1065|
+-------+---------+
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But, I cannot generate a 'df' with the sql query due to the error "Cannot have map type columns in DataFrame".

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. Alternative would be `df.selectExpr('user_id',"explode(transform(sport_ids, x->map_values(x)[0]))").show()`

Comment: in your code "df.selectExpr('user_id',"explode(transform(sport_ids, x->map_values(x)[0]))").show()", how to get 'df' ? thanks

Comment: I created the df as follws `df=spark.createDataFrame([('aca' ,      [ {'sport_id': '5818'}, {'sport_id': '6712'}, {'sport_id': '1065'} ])],
('user_id'   ,  'sport_ids'))`. For you, save your example into a df.  For instance, you can say `df= `"""
            select user_id, sport_ids
            from tab""" `

Comment: thanks, but, I have to get the original data from the table by running the query "select distinct, user_id, sport_ids  from tab" in jupyter notebook. It will access the presto db and get the "df". But, I got error "Cannot have map type columns in DataFrame" in OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can process json data (`json_parse`, cast to array of json and `json_extract_scalar` - for more json functions - [see here](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html)) and flatten ([`unnest`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest)) on presto side:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(user_id, sport_ids) AS (
    VALUES 
        ('aca', '[ {"sport_id": "5818"}, {"sport_id": "6712"}, {"sport_id": "1065"} ]')
) 

-- query
select user_id,
    json_extract_scalar(record, '$.sport_id') sport_id
from dataset,
    unnest(cast(json_parse(sport_ids) as array(json))) as t(record)
```

Output:

| user_id | sport_id |
| --- | --- |
| aca | 5818 |
| aca | 6712 |
| aca | 1065 |